# Preferred UI element to display list filters on Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want the user to be able to filter a list of items that is shown in a `ListView` by category; for example red, blue, green.

On iOS there is an element that shows items (such as the categories red, blue and green) in a horizontal list. This element is scrollable, as the list of categories might be longer than the screen's width.

On Android this could be done using a horizontal `ListView`, but this solution seems rather unelegant. https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android

What would be the best practice to provide an UI element to filter a list on Android? It wouldn't have to be a horizonal list.

Comment: The question is very common. Take a loot at [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) or at [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)(single-choice list or raido group).

Comment: Thanks, but for my use case spinners did not work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being sure what you exactly want to display, is this what you're looking for?

[image: Android horizontal lists]

From [Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html)

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I missed that :) The keyword would have been the FragmentStatePagerAdapter : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html